# Getting 404 in django. even user exist in database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Well i am getting 404 error even my user exist in database i tried to solve this but i couldn't can you guys help me. I really need help.

notes/views.py

```
class NotesListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    login_url = '/accounts/login/'
    model = Notes
    context_object_name = 'notes_data'
    # paginate_by = 
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(auth.models.User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))  
        return Notes.objects.filter(author=user).order_by('-create_date')
```

if i comment out the **user** line and in return line i replace user variable with user primary key than it shows all notes related to that user. But obviously i can't use same primary key in views or every user so i need to grab specific user and show him its notes list. and I am unable to do this. I need little help can you guys help me.?

notes/urls.py

```
app_name = 'notes'

urlpatterns = [
    path ('create/',views.NotesCreateView.as_view(),name = 'notes_create'),
    path ('detail/<int:pk>',views.NotesDetailView.as_view(),name = 'notes_detail'),
    path('list/<str:username>',views.NotesListView.as_view(),name='notes_list'),
    path('delete/<int:pk>',views.NotesDeleteView.as_view(),name='notes_delete'),
    path('update/<int:pk>',views.NotesUpdateView.as_view(),name ='notes_update'),
]
```

Comment: can you share your `urls.py` where you call `NotesListView`?

Comment: What does your URL look like? I see there is `username` param you're passing?

Comment: I have add my urls.py in my question you can see If i am missing something there.

Answer (score 0):

I asssume that you're fetching notes like this: `/list?username=myuser`
In this case you can retrieve `username` param from `request` object like this:

```py
def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(auth.models.User, username=self.request.GET.get('username'))
        return Notes.objects.filter(author=user).order_by('-create_date')
```

Comment: Now the error has been changed it says that : AttributeError at /notes/list/

'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'query_params'

Comment: Updated, should have been `GET` instead of `query_params`

Comment: Could you please show your URL query? How are you fetching your notes? Do you pass `username` query param?

Comment: Can you tell me if I add username parameter in url of notelistview. How can I add link in template. Like if i simply add simply {% url 'notes:notes_list' %} than it troughs an error :NoReverseMatch at /notes/create/

Reverse for 'notes_list' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['notes/list/(?P<username>[^/]+)$']

Comment: I have add URLs in my question

Answer (score 0):

You have declared the following pattern in your urls.py

```py
path('list/', views.NotesListView.as_view(), name='notes_list')
```

But then in your view you are trying to get the username through url parameter via `self.kwargs.get('username')`.

If you want to have access to the `username`, you need to call your url with a parameter:

- `127.0.0.1:8000/list/bob/`

And then rewrite your urlpattern, so it can accept `bob` as `username` parameter:

```py
path('list/<str:username>/', views.NotesListView.as_view(), name='notes_list')
```

Then in `self.kwargs` you will have `{'username': 'bob'}`.

Another approach is using `GET` instead of an `URL` parameter.

So if you call:

- `127.0.0.1:8000/list?username=bob`

you will have it via `self.request.query_params.get('username')`